# How can I invoke SQL Server msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail from Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I must use SQL Server procedure `sp_send_dbmail` to send some mails from an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework.

How can I do it using both plain SQL query and mapped models?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create the stored procedure like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendEmail]
    @profile_name VARCHAR(100),
    @recipients VARCHAR(1000),
    @copy_recipients VARCHAR(1000),
    @body NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @body_format VARCHAR(100),
    @subject NVARCHAR(1000),
    @file_attachments VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = @profile_name,
        @recipients = @recipients,
        @copy_recipients = @copy_recipients,
        @body = @body,
        @body_format = @body_format,
        @subject = @subject,
        @file_attachments = @file_attachments
END
GO
```

Then you add this stored procedure to the entity framework.
So you can use sp_send_dbmail like other function imports.